# Skip column in PageBlockSection

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, pageblocksection, pageblocksectionitem

So I have too much padding between fields within a PageBlockSection.  I have 3 columns, so to reduce the padding between fields I created 4 columns.  How can I skip a column to force the next PageBlockSectionItem in a new row.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Costs" id="CostsSection" columns="4">  
                  <!-- Costs-->
                  <!-- before position-->
                  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem HelpText="{!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.Rpt_Position_Support_Prior_to_STAR__c.inlineHelpText}">
                        {!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.Rpt_Position_Support_Prior_to_STAR__c.label}
                        <apex:inputField id="beforePosition" value="{!Application__c.Rpt_Position_Support_Prior_to_STAR__c}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

How can I force this on a new row and skip a column? Basically, I want Field, Field, Field, SKIP, [new row because only 4 columns], field, field, field, SKIP, etc...

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert an empty section item after the third:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
```

Comment: it's beautiful in it's simplicity!